# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: Fragment1 with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have used `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for `Viewpager` and It's working fine if I set adapter before api call. If I set adapter after some time I getting exception(I set adapter only once).

I don't know actually what's exact issue and solution.

Kindly check below code for reference

**Adapter :**

```
class MyPagerAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    fm: FragmentManager,
    private val event: EventInfoResponse
) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fm,
        BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT
    ) {
    private val fragmentsList = arrayListOf<Fragment>()
    val fragmentTitleList = arrayListOf<String>()


    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> Fragment1.newInstance(event)
            else -> Fragment2.newInstance(event.id!!)
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "title 1"
            else -> "title 2"
        }
    }
}
```

**Applying adapter :**

```
 vpEvent.apply {
            adapter = MyPagerAdapter(requireContext(),childFragmentManager,event!!)
            tlEvent.setupWithViewPager(this)
        }
```

**Exception :**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: Fragment1{9b6bafd (10e16e31-8262-4161-aeff-c78e1180030f) id=0x7f0a065f android:switcher:2131363423:0}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1379)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:399)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you directly instance `Fragment` in `Adapter`. you should create instance of fragment outside from `Adapter` and inject to `Adapter` and via `getItem()` method introduce ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍created `Fragment` to `Adapter`.

Comment: before  fragment was created outside of adapter. and it's not cause of issue

Comment: @RajasekaranM Do u sure that u don't same create instance fragment?